# How to change Android Studio default layout

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-constraintlayout

When you create a `blank_acitivity` it gives you a `ConstraintLayout`. How should one delete it. I know I can hight `ConstraintLayout` and do a rename refactor or should I just remove some of the code if I want to change it to a `gridLayout` or `LinearLayout` (I can not seem to be able to delete it without erasing it)?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch to "Text" tab in the editor. 
On the top remove ***android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout*** and type in ***LinearLayout*** or any other layout you want.